# How to set custom spacing margin value in Material UI Grid

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I need to set specific spacing value between Grid items in Material UI.
Bellow is the code I have:

```
<Grid container spacing={1}>
    <Grid item xs={6}>Node 1</Grid>
    <Grid item xs={6}>Node 2</Grid>
    ...etc
</Grid>
```

The problem is the margin when I set `spacing={1}` is a little bigger than what I want. How can I set custom value for margin between items?

Comment: tried broken values ? Or overwrite styles with a custom class or even inline styles...

Answer (score 1):

By adding styles and classname using MUI's makeStyles()

Probably this way you can do it:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Grid, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
function GridT() {
  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    gridItem: {
      padding: theme.spacing(0.5),
    }
  }));

  const styles = useStyles();

  return (
    <Grid container>
      <Grid className={styles.gridItem} item xs={6}>
        Node 1
      </Grid>
      <Grid className={styles.gridItem} item xs={6}>
        Node 2
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default GridT;
```

Code sandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-architecture-qt5p5

Comment: I tried decimal values, it does not work.

Comment: Alright I was under bad impression that it will work, wasn't really aware of it, so I've updated the answer, with working example!

Comment: This would add padding around `container` grid, not child items

Comment: So instead of adding the spacing to parent you can apply it to child elements, I have updated the answer with codesandbox example

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom class and add to your grid, for example:

```css
grid: {
   margin: '5px'
}
```

```html
<Grid className={classes.grid}>
   ....
</Grid>
```

Comment: this would add margin around `container` Grid, items would not be affected.

Comment: You could add a margin to each item of the grid